How to filter a sequence (\seq_set_filter:NNn) by dropping items that contain a given string?
With expl3, it's easy to filter a sequence by dropping items that equals a given string (“bar” in the following MCE):
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {foo,bar,baz}

\seq_set_filter:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
{
  \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {bar} { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool }
}
\seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq

% \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {foo,bar,baz}
% \seq_set_filter:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
% {
%   \str_if_in:nnTF {#1} {ba} { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool }
% }
% \seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

But, if one wants to drop the items that contains a given string (“ba” in the previous MCE) by relying on \str_if_in:nnTF instead of \str_if_eq:nnTF, it doesn't work: uncommenting the commented lines leads to the error:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
l.16 }

Do you know how to filter a sequence by dropping items that contain a given string (with \seq_set_filter:NNn)?
BTW, I know I could have used \str_if_eq_p:nn {#1} {bar} instead of \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {bar} { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool } in the MCE above but I wanted to draw the parallel with \str_if_in which has no \str_if_in_eq: form: I wonder why BTW.

\str_if_in:nnTF doesn't qualify in a Boolean expression, because it's not expandable.
Your first filter should better be
\seq_set_filter:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
{
  \bool_if_p:n { ! \str_if_eq_p:nn {#1} {bar} }
}

using predicates, but it's stylistic.
Only predicates (or equivalent constructions) are allowed in a boolean expression.

Why such a difference between \str_if_eq:nnTF and \str_if_in:nnTF? I do you know why \str_if_in_eq: is not provided?

@DenisBitouzé Because it can't be made expandable.

That's sounds weird that one can be made expandable and the another one can't for at a first glance so close commands.

@DenisBitouzé \str_if_eq:nnTF is built upon the primitive \pdfstrcmp (called \strcmp in XeTeX). As far as I remember, there was discussion about using \pdfmatch but this led to nothing because its behavior is very difficult to control.
